# show divs that have their ID stored in php array

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `php array` which stores `divs IDs`. I also have this **JS** function:

```
function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}
```

I want to use this function to show the divs one after another when i click on a single button in my html page (*Click button -> show div, Click same button again-> Show the next div, ...*).

I have tried looping through the php array, inserting **html** code for button in between and using the `onclick` HTML attribute.

```
<?php foreach ($subscheds as $subsched): ?>   
<button type="button" onclick="show('<?php print $subsched['id'] ?>');" 
                      class="btn btn-success" style="float:left;">+</button>        
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This generates as much buttons as there are divs and that is not what I need.

Comment: could you explain "What you actually want?"

Comment: You could add the attribute `hidden` to all but the first one. Then when the first button is clicked remove the hidden attribute from the next one, and so on. Assuming you are using ID numbers, just add `1` to get to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

Your php:

```
$divs = ["no1", "no2", "no3"];
```

Your html/javascript
    
        .hidden{ display: none; }

```
<button id="showDiv">Show an extra div</button>

<div class="hidden" id="no1">no1</div>
<div class="hidden" id="no2">no2</div>
<div class="hidden" id="no3">no3</div>

<script>
    // Track the number of divs currently not hidden
    var divsShown = 0;
    // The array with div id's
    var divs = <?php echo json_encode($divs); ?>;

    // Event handler, when the button is clicked
    document.getElementById("showDiv").onclick = function(){
        //  remove the hidden class
        document.getElementById(divs[divsShown]).className = "";
        // increase the number of divs shown
        divsShown++;

        // Hide the button when all divs are shown
        if(divsShown == divs.length) { document.getElementById("showDiv").className = "hidden";}
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all `DIVs` one-by-one after clicking on **same button** then,

just take all `ids` from php and use them in javascript. 
Like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var strIds = <?php foreach ($subscheds as $subsched):    
print $subsched['id'] .","
endforeach ?>; // this will create a string with comma separated ids at server-side only. (like 1,2,3,4,)
var arrIds = strIds.split(',');
var i = 0; // global variable to hold index value

function show() {
    if(i < (arrIds.length-1)) { // minus 1 to avoid last empty id
        document.getElementById(arrIds[i]).style.display = 'block';
        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps, let me know if you want more help. Thanks.

**Note:** Please verify PHP code (loop and concatenation) once as I'm not a PHP guy :)